# Sum of a list in R data frame

Tags: r, purrr, method-chaining

I have a column of type "list" in my data frame, I want to create a column with the sum.

[image: my list column]

I guess there is no visual difference, but my column consists of `list(1,2,3)`s and not `c(1,2,3)`s :

```
tibble(
  MY_DATA = list(
    list(2, 7, 8),
    list(3, 10, 11),
    list(4, 2, 8)
  ),
  NOT_MY_DATA = list(
    c(2, 7, 8),
    c(3, 10, 11),
    c(4, 2, 8)
  )    
)
```

[image]

Unfortunately when I try
`mutate(NEW_COL = MY_LIST_COL_D %>% unlist() %>% sum())`
the result is that every cell in the new column contains the sum of the *entire* source column (so a value in the millions)

I tried `reduce` and it did work, but was slow, I was looking for a better solution.

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `purrr::map_dbl`, which should return a vector of type `double`:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df = tibble(
  MY_LIST_COL_D = list(
    c(2, 7, 8),
    c(3, 10, 11),
    c(4, 2, 8)
  )
)

df %>% 
  mutate(NEW_COL= map_dbl(MY_LIST_COL_D, sum), .keep = 'unused')
#   NEW_COL
    <dbl>
# 1      17
# 2      24
# 3      14
```

Is this what you were looking for? If you don't want to remove the list column just disregard the `.keep` argument.

**Update**
With the underlying structure being lists, you can still apply the same logic, but one way to solve the issue is to `unlist`:

```
df = tibble(
  MY_LIST_COL_D = list(
    list(2, 7, 8),
    list(3, 10, 11),
    list(4, 2, 8)
  )
)

df %>% 
  mutate(NEW_COL = map_dbl(MY_LIST_COL_D, ~ sum(unlist(.x))), .keep = 'unused')
#   NEW_COL
#     <dbl>
# 1      17
# 2      24
# 3      14
```

Comment: thanks- but underneath, my individual data points are not of type `c(1,2,3)` but `list(1,2,3)`, and so the above fails with: `invalid 'type' (list) of argument`

Comment: I tried to update my answer to reflect your comment. Let me know if this works.

Comment: wow. yes, thanks. I used an image in my post because I was trying to express the fact that my data was `list()` and not `c()` but I guess there is no visual difference. I must have tried every combination of map() and unlist() but combining them all in one shot, i.e. `map_dbl(~ sum(unlist(.x)))` did the trick. I am very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rowwise` in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(NEW_COL = sum(MY_LIST_COL_D))
```

`rowwise` will also make your attempt work :

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(NEW_COL = MY_LIST_COL_D %>% unlist() %>% sum())
```

---

Can also use `sapply` in base R :

```
df$NEW_COL <- sapply(df$MY_LIST_COL_D, sum)
```